# What is the difference between "Shell" and "Shell PLC"?

Tags: dividends, shares

I see two shares which seem to be of the same company:

- [Shell (Royal Dutch Shell) (A)](https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/shell-aktie): WKN: A0D94M; ISIN: GB00B03MLX29
- [Shell PLC](https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/shell_b-aktie): WKN: A0ER6S; ISIN: GB00B03MM408

What exactly is the difference between the two? Is there a difference for the dividend?

Answer (score 3):

They are two different [classes of shares](https://www.shell.com/investors/retail-shareholder-information/information-on-shares.html) in the company that arose from the merger of Royal Dutch (a Dutch company) into Shell (a British compnay), and seem to differ primarily in tax treatment on dividends:

> Class A ordinary shares and Class B ordinary shares have identical rights, except related to the dividend access mechanism, which applies only to the Class B ordinary shares.
>
> Dividends paid on Class A ordinary shares have a Dutch source for tax purposes and are subject to Dutch withholding tax (see note 1 - Taxation). It is the expectation and the intention, although there can be no certainty, that holders of Class B ordinary shares will receive dividends via the dividend access mechanism (see note 2 - Dividend Access Mechanism).
>
> Any dividends paid via the dividend access mechanism will have a UK source for Dutch and UK tax purposes; there will be no UK or Dutch withholding tax on such dividends.

The [company website](https://www.shell.com/investors/retail-shareholder-information/information-on-shares.html) has more detailed information.

Comment: I believe the main point underlying the two classes of shares is that Shell is "dual-listed" in the UK and the Netherlands. I don't understand the finer detail of the consequences of that though.

Comment: Actually it _was_ dual-listed until it was unified in 2005 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Dutch_Shell), but I also do not know the full consequences of that action.